# Best way to validate source of API request

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I am trying to develop a PHP RESTful web service. What is the best way to securely validate the source of request?

Firewall is an option but I want to do some application level validation.

Comment: Can you go as far as checking the ip address of the remote server? or will there be too many different clients?

Comment: HMAC? use encryption and a auth token?

Comment: @drew010 I will use firewall to block other IPs, but I need application level protection as well. Thanks

Comment: @miki Thanks. Can you please suggests some guide to implement auth token system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [mutual authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) with https.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest some guide.